# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:Misplaced argument matcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, error-handling, mockito, dropwizard

**My code**

```
@Path("/apiajax/*/*")
@GET
public String handleFooJson(@Context UriInfo context) {
    return null;
}
```

**My test is**

```
Mockito.when(Bar.handleFooJson(Mockito.any(UriInfo.class))).thenReturn(null);
```

**I got error**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced argument matcher detected here: Mockito.when(Bar.handleFooJson(Mockito.any(UriInfo.class))).thenReturn(null); 

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.

    Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:

    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
```

I don't understand the description. How I test it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough point to add comment, but I would like to add that, please check you are mocking some method that can be mocked. Please read that in the error,

> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot > be mocked.
>   **Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified**: final/private/equals()/hashCode().

Also static method cannot be mocked, which I think is the case here.

```
Mockito.when(Bar.handleFooJson(Mockito.any(UriInfo.class))).thenReturn(null);
```

Bar look like a Class not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you have final method in class which you are mocking then

We need to add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:

mock-maker-inline

please refer article https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final